# Calling methods from main

Tags: java

I have a problem with calling a method. For example, I want the following program to have two methods:

- the first one is to check if the year is leap or not,
- the second one is to display the number of days in the month

I can't call the methods in `main`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYearCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LeapYearCheck ob = new LeapYearCheck();
        ob.isLeapYear();
        ob.daysInMonth();
    }

    static void isLeapYear() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        if (year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 == 0) {
            System.out.println(year + " is leap year:");
        } else {
            System.out.println(year + " is not leap year:");
        }
    }

    static void daysInMonth() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a month :");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        int year = 0;
        if (month == 2) {
            System.out.println("There are 29 days in February: " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 1) {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in January " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 2) {
            System.out.println("The are 28 days in February " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 3) {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in March " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 4) {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in April  " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 5) {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in May " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 6) {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in June  " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 7) {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in July  " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 8) {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in August " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 9) {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in September  " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 10) {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in  October " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 11) {
            System.out.println("The are 30 days in November " + year + " year");
        } else if (month == 12) {
            System.out.println("The are 31 days in December " + year + " year");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Month, Please enter a number between 1 & 12 Merci: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry about that and cheers mate ;/

Comment: cheers Philipp I appreciate it

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The program runs quite fine for me (although there are some logic errors)

Comment: Well , other than the unnecessary object creation , what's wrong ?

Comment: For example first you need to enter number and then it ask you to enter a year and  on the end there is display  "0 year "  "1
Enter a year: 
400
400 is leap year:
Enter a month :
5
The are 31 days in May 0 year" any idead ?

Comment: Yeah I don't see a problem. Although you should make the methods public/protected/private and either NOT make them static or NOT create an object to call those methods (static methods should be called in a static way and since you're in the same class that would mean just calling them directly, no need for an instance). Oh and of course your calculation of whether it's a leap year or not is actually not correct, but it's not causing the program to fail.

Comment: wats the error/exception you are getting?

Comment: Umm , is your problem that the year you entered first doesnt get displayed in the second print statement ?

Comment: The methods a re declared static! Just call them like this `daysInMonth()`. You don't need an object!

Answer (score 5):

The methods are declared "static". In Java, that means the method is available for the *class*, not for objects of the class.

To be clear: I understand your problem to be that when calling the second method, the year from the first method isn't available anymore, right?

That's because you don't store it in an instance variable, but in a variable local to the method. Local variables are gone once the method has completed. Instead, create an instance variable for your class, e.g. "private int year;". In the first method, then use "this.year = ..." to assign a value to the variable. In the second method, use "this.year" to access it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will compile and run (I've just tried it), but you *shouldn't* call static methods via expressions like this:

```
LeapYearCheck ob = new LeapYearCheck();
ob.isLeapYear();
ob.daysInMonth();
```

You should *either* make these instance methods *or* call them as static methods, optionally qualifying them with the type name:

```
LeapYearCheck.isLeapYear(); // Explicit
daysInMonth(); // Implicit
```

Calling static methods as if they were instance methods leads to confusion - it *looks* like it depends on the instance, but it doesn't.

The next oddity is here:

```
static void isLeapYear() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int month = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
```

Your waiting for user input but without telling the user why - and you're then *ignoring* the month anyway (which makes sense, as it's irrelevant to working out whether a year is a leap year or not). Just get rid of this line:

```
int month = input.nextInt();
```

Additionally, this logic is broken:

```
if (month == 2) {
    System.out.println("There are 29 days in February: " + year + " year");
} else if (month == 1) {
    System.out.println("The are 31 days in January " + year + " year");
} else if (month == 2) {
    System.out.println("The are 28 days in February " + year + " year");
```

Then for the `daysInMonth` method:

- You're not asking about the year
- You're not trying to detect leap years before you report that there are 29 days in February

Basically the code is a bit of a mess at the moment, but your problem of not being able to call methods from `main` should *not* be an issue...

EDIT: As noted, your leap year calculations are wrong anyway - I'm assuming that the calendar side of things is part of the goal of the exercise, but normally it would be better to use `Calendar` (and its subclasses) or [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to start with.

Comment: This is a good answer, I'd just like to add that when testing date things like this, he should probably consider using a Calendar (most likely a GregorianCalendar) rather than the (incorrect) manual testing he's currently doing. GregorianCalendar presents you with a isLeapYear method.

Comment: Well, i was tald that when a main mathod is static it can be accessed only via other static methods isn't it right ?

Comment: @Kiril: Well that's talking about *calling* a main method, but it's wrong anyway. It's important to really understand what `static` means - I suggest you read through a book or tutorial *very carefully*.

Comment: @Kiril The main thing to understand is the difference between an _object_ and a _class_. Static methods belong to classes and non static methods belong to objects. Objects are individual instances of a class, in your case `LeapYearCheck` is your class and `ob` is your object.

Answer (score 0):

This should run. Maybe not correctly, but it'll run. Perhaps you're referring to the warning you get on the two method calls in your main method. You see, your two methods are static. A static method doesn't require an object instance to be called. Yet you're calling them on a LeapYearCheck instance. This is allowed (it'll delegate to the proper class), just not necessary.