# Having Problems With do...while Loop

Tags: java

I have a little problem with this `do while` loop; when I run the program it is working, at least partially, what I mean is first you need to make a choice for convertion from C to F or from F to C and after you enter the values the program stops what I want to do is to keep asking for values until you enter 3. I tried to do it with a `do while` loop but it is not working so if someone has any ideas I would be grateful. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DegreesInConversion2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Conversion table: ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        do {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1 for convertion from Celsious to Fahrenhait: ");
            System.out.println("2 for convertion froom Fahrenheit to Celsious: ");
            System.out.println("3 for Exit: ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Make a choice between 1 - 3 ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter temperature in Celsious: ");
                double cel = input.nextDouble();
                if (cel < -273.15) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid values, please enter temperature greater than -273.15 in C:");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You enetered " + cel + "C " + "which is " + (((cel * 9) / 5) + 32) + "F");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter temperature in Farhneit: ");
                double far = input.nextDouble();
                if (far < -459.67) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid values, please enter temperature greater than -459.67 in F:");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You enetered " + far + "F " + "which is " + (((far - 32) * 5) / 9) + "C");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Goodbyu have a nice day: ");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid entry: Please enter a number between 1-3:");
            }
        } while (choice != 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7928400/127035), here you're scanning for input before prompting the user for input.

You need to remove the second line below:

```
    System.out.println("Conversion table: ");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    do
```

With your code as is, it outputs

```
Conversion table:
```

and then blocks waiting for input. Whereas you want it instead to continue into the while loop and output

```
1 for convertion from Celsious to Fahrenhait:
2 for convertion froom Fahrenheit to Celsious:
3 for Exit:

Make a choice between 1 - 3
```

before blocking to scan for input.

As is, if you enter any number at the first block, your program enters the loop and behaves as you wanted. So you're nearly there!

Answer (score 0):

The code does work. the problem is most likely the

```
int choice = input.nextInt();
```

before the `do`

Remove this, and change

```
choice = input.nextInt();
```

to

```
int choice = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: I changed it and than when I compile it i got this message " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 choice cannot be resolved to a variable

 at DegreesInConversion2.main(DegreesInConversion2.java:48)"

Comment: where line 48 is   } while (choice != 3);

Comment: You sure you changed `choice = input.nextInt();` to `int choice = input.nextInt();`?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you have: `int choice = input.nextInt();` outside of the loop which is unnecessarily getting input before showing the menu, it seems to all work relatively fine. You can just declare `int choice` inside the loop where you have `choice = input.nextInt();` (ie. just change that to **`int`**`choice = input.nextInt();`).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and it works fine if you change the line `int choice = input.nextInt();` (just before your `do{} while()` block) into `int choice;`.

As others have already mentioned, you should not read input before your `do{} while()` block, since the question has not been asked yet.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the `break;` after your default case